# Send a value to last activity

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a basic app and I want to send a value of interest to last activity I am having total 8 activities so last activity contain 7int values so help me out how to write a code

Comment: have a look into intents, and how you can pass data from one Activity to another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)